# Angularfire2 multiple authentication options

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

How I can allow the users to choose their own authentication option?

Currently users can log-in using Facebook only, with the following setup as documented:

```
const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup
}
```

And simply in my component:

```
this.auth.login();
```

How I can allow the user to choose if to login via Facebook or using email and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `login()` call with specific provider and methods as such:

```
// Login with facebook
this.af.auth.login({
  provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup,
});

// Login with email and password
this.af.auth.login({
  email: 'lee@hwang.com',
  password: '******'
});
```